# jquery dropdown from mysql based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

**EDIT 2** Seemed it was a problem with a CSS class.

**EDIT** Strange enough it works on the public side of the site by not the priviate. It must be a css or conflict with another plugin.

Let me start out by saying I have very little jQuery experience and this is my first time dabbling with ajax.

What I am trying to do is dynamically populate drop-down data based on the selection of the previous drop down.

I have html that looks like this

```
        <label for="employee_type">Employee Type</label>
        <select name="employee_type" id="employee_type">
                 <option value="1" selected="selected">Team Member</option>
                 <option value="2">Supervisor</option>
                 <option value="3">Manager</option>
           </select>        

        <label for="manager">Reports To</label>
        <select name="manager" id="manager_name">
                  <option value="0" selected="selected">Please Select Employee Role</option>
           </select>
```

The Idea being that when an employee role or type is selected that the field below populates with all the managers who are higher up on the food chain.

I have a MYSQL select string written with php that is outputing some json using `json_encode` the output of that is

```
[{"id":"2","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}]
```

This is basicly just an array of all users and their names and id's to be shown in the array.

Here comes the tricky part, the ajax. I found [this tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/json-data-jquery-php-mysql/) which I've modified

```
    // attach a change handler to the form
  $("select#employee_type").change(function(){
   //get the mininimum employee level   
    var input = $("select#employee_type").val();
    //get the callback url
    var ajax_url = "/admin/employee/get_json/"+input;

   $.ajax({
      url:ajax_url,
      data:{ url:escape(ajax_url) },
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data){ 
              var select = $('#manager_name');
        var options = select.attr('options');
              $('option', select).remove();

        $.each(data, function(index, array) {
                options[options.length] = new Option(array['first_name']+ " "+array['last_name'],array['id']);
        })
                },

            error:function(xhr,err,e){ alert( "Error: " + err ); }
    }); // $.ajax()
    return false;
  }); // .submit()*/
```

This works about 78% of the way. It adds the correct options and value. Where it fails is that if I have  `$('option', select).remove();` (which is nessarry to make sure the vaules don't get added each time the field changes) The field gets removed when I try to click on it. I also think it would be a nice touch to remove the selected option (Please Select...).

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using .empty() instead of .remove() as that way you actually only delete the children of that element instead of the element itself.

```
success:function(data){ 
    var select = $('#manager_name');
        select.empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, array) {
               select.append(new Option(array['first_name']+ " "+array['last_name'],array['id']));
        })
},
```

I personally haven't used the new Option method, so I can't verify that it's correct.

A working solution should be http://jsfiddle.net/HffLg/10/

Comment: That mostly works, I'm having a problem now where I'm not able to select the first result. Not sure if this is related to your code or something else.

Comment: It seems that when I change the value of `#employee_type` I can't select the value of #manger_name especially if there is only one value. I can't click on the first vaule. I'm trying to figure out if it's a CSS problem but I'm pretty sure it's javascript related.

Comment: Could you provie an example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm either doing it wrong or can't because of the ajax call back. http://jsfiddle.net/HffLg/1/

Comment: http://hr.brandondukes.com/admin/employee/get_json/ is password protected, can you make it public, make a mock public method or move it to another directory?

Comment: You can now access a public version here: http://hr.brandondukes.com/employee/get_json You will need to append a permission to the end to see the json. For example http://hr.brandondukes.com/employee/get_json/1 will get anyone with greater than a permission of 1. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: I hate to say this but the latest revision dosen't seem to be working. If i troubleshot it seems the function is called on page load but never gets to the ajax call. It also seems it dosen't reinitiate on change.

Comment: I think my originally code worked with the addition of empty() it was actually a problem with the cms's css