# jquery empty() preventing select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, uniform, pyrocms

A while ago I posted this question asking how to get JSON data into jQuery dropdowns 
[jquery dropdown from mysql based on previous selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191222/jquery-dropdown-from-mysql-based-on-previous-selection)

Well the people here were awesome and I got a solution. The problem I'm having now is that the suggest solution dosen't work in my production enviorment but it does in my test.

In order to prevent duplicate entrees I am using jQuery `empty()` the problem is that using `empty()` seems to also be preventing me from selecting the first option.

this is the function that is generating the optiosn from JSON

```
function(data){

            var select = $('[name="employee_manager"]');
            select.empty();
            select.append(new Option(ucfirst('No Manager'),'100'));

            $.each(data, function(index, array) {

                    select.append(new Option(ucfirst(array['first_name'])+ " "+ucfirst(array['last_name']),array['id']));
            });
```

Is that an alternative to empty() that won't prevent selection?

**EDIT** This seems to only be a problem if there are fewer than two items being dynamically input
**EDIT 2** Here is the HTML. It seems that I can't select the first option if `empty()` is present

```
     <label for="manager">Reports To</label>
     <select name="employee_manager">
          <option value="1">Please Select Employee Role</option>
          <option value="2">John Doe</option>
          <option value="3">James Smith</option>
    </select>
```

**EDIT 3**

Looks like the empty class is adding a span to my select

```
<div class="selector">
<span style="-moz-user-select: none;">Jane  Smith</span>
    <select name="employee_manager" style="opacity: 0;">
         <option value="100">No Manager</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**EDIT 4**
Okay so here is a jsfiddle that shows the problem. I couldn't get the JSON data to load correctly but you can still see the problem if you attempt to click on the first item in the list. It seems that it's a problem with [uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/) as if uniform is removed it's not a problem
http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/xXUfp/1/

Comment: What do you mean by 'selecting'? I see nothing in your code that 'selects' an element.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question to include html that is doing the select.

Comment: looks like `data` is ajax response, what type is `data`? json?

Comment: @experimenX, yes. My form is retretreving the ajax fine. It's just that without `empty()` each time I select the list is repropegated. and with `empty()` I can't choose the first option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `empty()` to clear the options of drop down list. It's wrong, because it should be used to remove DOM children.

Instead use such code:

```
$("select[name='employee_manager'] > option").remove();
```

Edit: when using the jQuery `uniform` plugin, dynamically adding options is messing things up... one way around that does not require to go and try fix the plugin is to always have enough "dummy" options in place (e.g. 20 if that's the max amount of options) then change the text/value of those options and hide all others according to your data.
The proper JS code will now look like this:

```
var myData = [];
myData.push( { text: "Please Select A Manager (JS)", value: "null" } );
myData.push( { text: "No Manager", value: "100" } );
myData.push( { text: ucfirst("a third choice"), value: "42" } );
$.each(data, function(index, array) {
   myData.push( { text: ucfirst(array['first_name'])+ " " + ucfirst(array['last_name']), value: array['id'] } );
});

$("select[name='employee_manager'] > option").each(function(index) {
   if (index < myData.length) {
      $(this).text(myData[index]["text"]);
      $(this).val(myData[index]["value"]);                          
      $(this).show();
   }
   else {
        $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/xXUfp/2/).

Crude, but working.... :)

Comment: for some reason i'm having the same problem with remove. I think it's a css issue though. I'm getting the selected class added to a span. See edit 3 above.

Comment: @BrandonRandon well don't forget to check with firebug

Comment: @experimentX I am checking with firebug that's how i figured it's adding a span. No JS errors. not sure what else to look for or why it's adding a span.

Comment: @BrandonRandon well try somewhat similar to mine, though no guarantee

Comment: This works better than `empty()` but still didn't sovled the problem. My work around was to add `select.append(new Option(ucfirst('Please Select A Manager'),'null'));` as the first option and the user just can't select it which is fine.

Comment: @Brandon don't feel obliged to Accept the answer if it didn't fully solve your problem, let's try to nail it down. Can you reproduce this behavior without AJAX request? Can you put such example on jsFiddle?

Comment: @shadow, Edit 4 contains a link to a jsfiddle. I think it's a problem with uniformjs.

Comment: That worked, you're right crude but worked. Now I just need to figure out how to get a while loop into my php array for the dummy values but i'll open a new thread for that :) (PS, it's Bandon or Brooke not Brandon :P)

Comment: I think I spoke too soon.. `.push` seems to not be returning values but if i use `alert()` i get the values. not sure if it's a problem with the way the inputs are being created

Comment: @Bandon Oops! Should have looked more carefully - luckily you get notified as you're the OP here. :) Regarding `push()` it should not return anything, just push the given item into the array - post your new code and I'll try to see what might be wrong. Note that when you reach 12 edits your question will become Community Wiki.

Comment: @shadow, your code seemed to work fine after I got the PHP and "dummy" vaules all sorted out. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Well try something like this, but no guaranteed

```
$('<option></option>').val(100).html('No Manager').appendTo($(select));

$.each(data, function(index, array) {
    $('<option></option>').val(array['id']).html(ucfirst(array['first_name'])+ " "+ucfirst(array['last_name']).appendTo($(select));
});
```

Comment: This is still duplicating all fields. You also forgot an `)` but I fixed that. PS, it's "BandonRandon" not "BRandonRadon" :)

Comment: @BandonRandon sorry for that, because i have not tested it. best of luck ... Oops! had to edit again.